# Wix Display Results from refrenced table

Tags: database, database-connection, velo

i have two table in wix:
**Products**
**ProductCatgeories**

Products table has a field name "type" which is refrnced to ProductCatgeories table

i am trying to fill a table elent with a search results that will display the product title and it's type.

```
    wixData.query("Products").contains("title", $w('#txtSearch').value).find().then((results) => {
    let items = results.items;}
$w('#tblSearch').rows = items;
```

the above works fine !
however it only display the type id form ProductCategories table.
how can i achive that ?
Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
let cols = $w("#table1").columns;
cols = [];
cols.push({
    "id": "type",
    "dataPath": "productType.title",
    "label": "ProductType",
    "width": 70,
    "visible": true,
    "type": "string"
});

cols.push({
    "id": "title",
    "dataPath": "title",
    "label": "product",
    "width": 70,
    "visible": true,
    "type": "string"
});
$w('#table1').columns= cols;
wixData.query("Products").contains("title","חלב").include("productType").find().then((res)=>{
    var prods= res.items;
    console.log(prods[2]);
    $w('#table1').rows=prods;
});
```

all you need to do is use contain and it will immediatly connect the refrnced table.

you can later acces it by calling it's column name followed by dot and property  IE:

```
productType.title
```

and that's it !